# How to Compile the two procedure inside of package?

Tags: plsql, package, procedure

I have created three procedure inside of the package. Now want to compile the only two procedure inside of the package. 
Is it Possible, If yes means How?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. You compile can compile the package body separate from it's header, but not the individual methods in the package body, only the thing as a whole.

You can recompile it using the [`alter package` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_2005.htm). In its simplest form:

```sql
ALTER PACKAGE YourPackage COMPILE PACKAGE; -- Whole package
ALTER PACKAGE YourPackage COMPILE SPECIFICATION; -- Spec/header only
ALTER PACKAGE YourPackage COMPILE BODY; -- Body only
```

Comment: And the really nice thing about using a package (in case you think this is a bad thing), is that you can recompile the package body - where most of your changes will take place - without recompiling the package specification.

That's big, because it means that none of the other program units dependent on the package will be marked invalid and need recompilation. 

Change the package spec or schema-level procedure and all dependents are marked invalid.

Comment: I should have mentioned that. It is indeed one of the big advantages of packages!